# join two tables when first table ends

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like

```
tab 1 
Date        Product
29-05-2014  apple
30-05-2014  banana
31-05-2014  pink

tab 2
Date        Product
29-05-2014  red
30-05-2014  blue
31-05-2014  orange
01-06-2014  whit
02-06-2014  black

required table
Date        Product
29-05-2014  apple
30-05-2014  banana
31-05-2014  pink
01-06-2014  whit
02-06-2014  black
```

How do I join two tables when first table ends?

Comment: So you want to ignore `red, blue` and `orange` ?  Include anything with a date greater than the `max(date)` from `tab1` ?

Comment: second table joins to first from where first ends. Just from max date in table1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT T2.Date,COALESCE(T1.Product,T2.Product) as Product
FROM Tab2 T2 LEFT JOIN
     Tab1 T1 ON T1.Date=T2.Date
```

`COALESCE` will return T2.Product if T1.Product is null.
Result:

```
DATE        PRODUCT
29-05-2014  apple
30-05-2014  banana
31-05-2014  pink
01-06-2014  whit
02-06-2014  black
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4c50/1).